# click button color spread all over the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android application where when I click on a button (made with a Textview) I have a brief change background color (black to green) before changing of activity.

Sometimes, things go wild and the green color spread on other elements.

Green color everywhere instead of black background with bottom button which can become green on click:
[image: Green color everywhere instead of black background with bottom button which can become green on click]

Actually I am not sure at all that the green come from the button on click color. It might be another reason.

How can I get rid of this bug.?

Thank you for your help

Comment: edit your question to put some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally forced the background color programmatically in the onCreate...